# How do I increment a Google Sheets range via getRange?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function namedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i=3; i<504; i++) {
    var r = ss.getRange('A3:Q3'+i);
    ss.setNamedRange('Song'+i, r);
  }
}
```

The above formula, is not stepping thru the 500 song rows in my spreadsheet and naming each row, "Song 3" for row A3-Q3, etc. (starting at row 3 as I have headers in rows 1 and 2) as I expected.

So what I am trying to do is create named ranges for all 500 songs in the sheet.

What I am expecting:

```
Name - Range
Song3 - Songs!A3:Q3
Song4 - Songs!A4:Q4
Song5 - Songs!A5:Q5
etc.
```

What I am getting:

```
Song3 - Songs!A3:Q33
Song4 - Songs!A3:Q34
Song5 - Songs!A3:Q35
etc.
```

I have spent two days trying to track this down by searching (in vain). I'm sure it's easy. Anybody know how to do this?

## Improved version

Below is a "new and better" version of the script I am using (which also incorporates @Casper 's answer). It is "new" and "better" because it counts the number of columns in the sheet, rather than taking a static value which makes it more flexible as it will name a range the width of the sheet, no matter that width (as measured by columns).

```
function namedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //first column = 1
  var numcols = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(numcols);
  for(var i=101; i<501; i++) {
    var r = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,numcols);//row, column, num rows, num cols
    ss.setNamedRange('Song'+i, r);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've moved it all around. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You know, I'm a professional and an expert in my field (music). If you asked me for help in that field, I would either help you if I knew the answer, or tell you i didn't know the answer.

Comment: What are you using named ranges for?

Comment: The named ranges are used to pull data from this spreadsheet into other spreadsheets in separate workbooks.

Comment: You can better understand why I am naming ranges by referring to my answer to another question I asked at Stack Overflow (here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258142/import-named-range-data-between-google-workbooks/54819748#54819748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this I suppose:

```
function namedRanges() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i=3; i<504; i++) {
    var r = ss.getRange('A'+i+':Q'+i);
    ss.setNamedRange('Song'+i, r);
  }
}
```

Your original code was appending the row number to your static text:

```
var r = ss.getRange('A3:Q3'+i);
```

Basically reads as:

```
var r = ss.getRange('A3:Q3'+3);
```

The `+` sign concatenates `Q3` and `3` resulting in `Q33`. However, in my code you define the columns as static text and the row numbers as variable.

```
var r = ss.getRange('A'+i+':Q'+i);
```

Therefore reads as (i=3):

```
var r = ss.getRange('A'+3+':Q'+3);
```

Resulting in `A3:Q3`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome. That works. Saves me doing it manually 500 times. Very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Spoke too soon. The creation of the ranges is working fine, but because the "i" value is being interpreted as text, the ranges in the range list (to the right of the sheet, visible when you select "Named Ranges" from the  "Data" menu) are not calculated and created in numerical order, but text order, so for instance: Song9, Song99, rather than Song9, Song10. I know this is resulting from "i" being interpreted as text, not a numerical value, but I do not know the commands to get the script to read "i" as a number. (Also, any links to a resource where I can learn this stuff would be helpful.)

Comment: In the code, it's a integer concatenated with a string. As we concatenate this with a string, the output automatically becomes a string (since you cannot have an integer with non-numeric values). So what you're asking now is impossible. You might want to search for options to change the ordering of this list that you're talking about.

Comment: @BeeTee you actually cannot control the order of the named range display in sheets, they are always shown in alphabetical order. However, you could fix this by padding with zeros, so instead of song1 / song99 do song0001, and song0099. This adds some complexity to the code but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks much for input y'all. I think I can take it from here. I sort of already tried the padded zeros route. Think I'll go back to that.

Comment: Simple. Added rows up to 99 on sheet and then hid them (no songs in any of those rows). Set i to 100 and tested for less than 601 and all ranges came out in order: 100 to 600. Done. Thanks again.

Comment: The next step in this process is to find a value at the intersection of two named ranges. For instance, I want to extract to another sheet, the artist for Song100.  I have named the column where the artist info for each song is located "Artist" and so I need to address that intersection with something like this: var r = ss.getValue(at the intersection of Song100 & Artist)

Comment: Excel implements this rather simply: (https://excel.tv/intersection-operator-with-named-ranges-excel-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: Within the same workbook, =index(Artist,Song100) works perfectly. But, how to do it when you have separate workbooks?