# Import named range data between Google Workbooks

Tags: google-sheets, named-ranges

If within the same Google Sheets Workbook, the formula: index(namedRangeRow , namedRangeColumn) works beautifully to "pull" or extract the piece of data residing at the intersection of the named row and named column onto another Sheet in the SAME Workbook.

How do I write a formula to get the same effect when I want to pull data from a DIFFERENT Workbook? I presume it is importRange, but I can't seem to get that formula to recognize two named ranges and find the data at the intersection thereof.

The formula: importRange("key", "namedRangeRow") works great, but it pulls all the data in the target Workbook range. So, I presume it's some variation of that formula, I just can't find the right way to express the two ranges within the importRange function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in the image below pulls a value in a cell at the intersection of two named ranges from a separate Google spreadsheet (i.e., workbook). (Link to [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXJanN8ALe_lJQwVIa-jyio5y-Ya_pbJbH05a6M52Bg/edit#gid=453316492).)

[image: Set Lists Sheet]

The sheet where the data resides is below. ([Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpH_eYYiuvoix3mXzCjiTNiahunLz2Q3EXA_lCgMgGE/edit#gid=1286827341).)
[image: Song Catalog Sheet]

The SetLinkData sheet is the 2nd sheet in the Set List workbook as in the pic below and contains the ID of the Song Catalog sheet.

[image: SetLinkData sheet]